# Can Linux hostname be changed without machine first being unjoined from the domain?

Tags: linux, centos, active-directory, hostname

We are considering changing the hostname of a number of Windows/Linux machines, all of which are joined to a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain.

From past experience I know that a Windows member server can be re-named without it first being un-joining from the domain.

I'm not so sure about whether the Linux machines can be re-named without first being unjoined though.  In Googling around, I haven't found anything definitive on this.  Can they be renamed without being unjoined first?  Are there any known issues with doing that?  These are CentOS 6.8 machines, if that is important.